How to use Mobaxtem plugins (screen one)
I'm a mobaxterm user in windows 10. I saw in their plugins web that I could use a screen plugin https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/plugins.html
But, even  if I download the file from https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/plugins/Screen.mxt3 and placing it in the same folder as the moba excecutable, restarting the app doesn't seem to be any kind of change.
Please, could somebody try to explain to me how should I use this plugin (and others as well).
Thanks a lot in advance!!

thanks a lot for your answer.
I my case, I'm using windows 10 and mobaxterm as my usuall ssh client for all my severs.
I had already think that maybe that was the use for the plugins, but unfortunally, I wasn't able to make it work. In this example, I downloaded and placed the screen plugin in the same folder as mobaxterm. I restarted the moba app, and in a new shell session (powershell one) I tried to use the screen command. Las time I tried that, I was unable to find any app with name screen, but now (i don't know what I did to make it "work"), I can get a different message, as you can see in the pic.
So, if I'm right, the plugin works like if I download the command binary to my client computer, right? I thought it was not this way because las time I tried, no binary with name screen was being found on the command line
Now, I'll have to find the way to make it work with a normal user
Thanks a lot to everybody for yout help and time!
Screen pic

Have you looked through the settings perhaps?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Actually, my problem is that I can see that we have multiple plugins to use with moba. But, I don't know how to use them. Something like the screen plugin sounds interesting for me, as I used to work with screen in my linux servers, but I don't know what does this screen plugin provide to mobaxterm. I mean... I can use the screen app from any linux client I have and that have the screen app installed. What is the purpose of a screen plugin for moba? How can I use it, and what does it provide?
I read their plugins website and I didn't find any doc...
Thanks for your answers!

@music2myear yes, I've already checked in the settings, but I was unable to see any kind of change.
Thanks

Your comment above should  be an edit to your question. Your goal is to improve your question. Another question you need to answer is "what research have you done regarding how to use plugins in this software?" This seems like the sort of thing someone else has probably asked on the internet, so I'm guessing there is information out there. What have you done yourself to find this information.

What this plugin add is a program, named screen. It is used from command line and you can create virtual screens for programs. Maybe you can consult with man page of screen.
If you have defined real (not virtual) root of your can install the utility via command:
apt install screen

